# passing JSTL to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl

I want to pass JSTL from my onclick event to javascript. My onclick looks like this,

```
onclick="cancelButtonAction(<c:out value='${loop.index}'/>, <c:out value="${iList.inStr}"/>);"
```

and my cancelButtonAction function is,

```
function cancelButtonAction(index, inSchLdTsStr){
document.getElementById('loadDate'+index).value = inSchLdTsStr;    
}
```

But this wouldnt work. Onclick the event is not getting triggered. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you see any JS error in console ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a string you need to add the `'` or `"` for the parameter, look the code below:

```
onclick="cancelButtonAction(<c:out value='${loop.index}'/>, '<c:out value="${iList.inStr}"/>);'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string is terminated in between

use like this.

```
onclick="cancelButtonAction(<c:out value='${loop.index}'/>, <c:out value='${iList.inStr}'/>);"
```